# My div includes an element, but the element doesn't show up when iterating using .children()

Tags: javascript, html, django, show-hide

Here's my html that I'm using in a Django application:

```
<div id="mahal_questions" class="showHide_div">
                        {{soldier.mahal_status.label_tag}}
                        {{soldier.mahal_status}}
    {{soldier.mahal_status.errors}}
                        {{soldier.mahal_program.label_tag}}
                        {{soldier.mahal_program}}
    {{soldier.mahal_program.errors}}
    <p>
                        {{soldier.mahal_id.label_tag}}
                        {{soldier.mahal_id}}
    {{soldier.mahal_id.errors}}</p>
</div>
                        {{soldier.currently_serving.label_tag}}
                        {{soldier.currently_serving}}
<div id="currently_serving_questions" class="showHide_div">
                        {{soldier.idf_id.label_tag}}
                        {{soldier.idf_id}}
    {{soldier.idf_id.errors}}
    <p></p> <!--prevents the error message from running into the next label-->
                        {{soldier.army_unit.label_tag}}
                        {{soldier.army_unit}}
    {{soldier.army_unit.errors}}
                        <p>{{soldier.tafkid.label_tag}}
                        {{soldier.tafkid}}
                            {{soldier.tafkid.errors}}</p>
</div>
```

I have two divs here that each include 3 fields.
mahal_questions includes
mahal_status, mahal_program and mahal_id
currently_serving_questions includes
idf_id, army_unit, and tafkid fields.

For some reason though, when I loop through my divs and within each div, loop through my elements, I only see the first two elements in each div. The last element is ignored. (I think this problem may have started when I added in some `<p>` elements, but I'm not sure.)

Here's my js (the method is meant to loop through each div on the page and if the div is hiding, loop through the elements and erase their value on submit so the hidden fields' values don't get sent to the db):

```
 $('#intake_form').submit(function() {
  var showhideDivList = document.getElementsByClassName("showHide_div"); //To avoid errors on a page with no show/hides
        if (showhideDivList.length > 0) {
            //get each show/hide div
            Array.from(showhideDivList).forEach(function (div) {
                console.log(div);
                //if this div is hidden
                if ($(div).is(":hidden")){
                    // //for each element that is going to be shown/hidden within the div
                    var elements = $(div).children();
                    console.log("elements.length:" + elements.length);
                    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                        var element = elements.eq(i);
                        console.log(element);
                        console.log("value", element.val());
                        element.val("");
                        console.log("value", element.val());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
});
```

Comment: could you show the rendered html please

Comment: Those `<p>` elements will be children of the `<div>` elements, and your loop does not iterate within those.

Comment: In general use "view page source" in your browser. Once you have established that the content you expected from your template is indeed in there, you know that you are dealing wityh a JQuery or Javascript problem, not a Django one.

Comment: Look at the [docs for `children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) to understand what your loop is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Pointy's answer in the comments.
The problem was that I had the two "missing" fields wrapped in `<p>` tags, so the .children() function was grabbing the `<p>`s and not the elements within the `<p>`s.  Thank you, Pointy!

So to fix this, I just put `<p></p>` before the mahal_id and tafkid fields to push their labels onto the line after the error messages and then they are directly under their respective divs and will be included in the results from the .children() function.